# flextable with lapply in pptx can not output table

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, lapply, flextable

I got trouble in knit table with lapply and for loop function, I try with the simple code with flextable() in only one data.frame, things go well , but not lapply with list formate nested dataframes, well,.Rmd file it runs well, what should I do?

THANKS A LOT!

```
 for (i in  ACC) {print(colformat_num(flextable(i), digits=3))}
```

```
try=lapply(ACC, FUN = function(i) { colformat_num(flextable(i), digits=3))})
print(try)
```

[image]

Comment: PowerPoint won't let you output several tables in a single placeholder.

Comment: wawawawa! Thanks a lot for your comment! I really hope you could answer my questions, so I should give up this try.

Comment: If in a loop and only graphical and tabular reporting, maybe you will have less pain with officer.